# Rendering an Array of Components in React - not updating and getting different results

Tags: reactjs

im a little confused. I thought you could simply render an array of components like this:

```js
// in render function
const components = [<Comp1 />, <Comp2 />, ...]

return ( <div>
{components}
</div>)
```

this seems to work as long as I dont try to update the array.
here is a little app, that adds a block if you click the button
and then renders the list of blocks via two methods: map and just the list.

in my create-react-app project only the mapped list gets updates, but as a codepen, both lists get updated. whats happening here?

codepen: https://codepen.io/bomelino/pen/eYYjNPG

```js
// create-react-app project
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

class Block extends React.Component {
  render (){
    return <div className="Block" >B</div>
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.key = 0
    this.state = {
      blocks : [<Block key={this.key} />],
    }
  }

  add=()=>{
    console.log("add")
    var blocks = this.state.blocks
    this.key += 1
    blocks.push(<Block key={this.key}/>)
    console.log("blocks:",blocks)
    this.setState({
      blocks : blocks
    })
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
    <input type="button" onClick={this.add} value="add" />
    {this.state.blocks.map((item,index)=>{
        return item
    })}

    {this.state.blocks.length}  

    {this.state.blocks}
    </div>
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Just as a side note, never mutate the state, like you're doing with `.push`

Comment: @Jayce444 no, thats not a sidenote, thats the answer. i added ```var blocks = [... this.state.blocks]``` and now it works, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @Jayce444 said, i'm mutating the state and that's not good,

simply changing one line

```js
// in add()
var blocks = [...this.state.blocks]
```

does the trick

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each element in the array a key:

```
// in render function
const components = [<Comp1 key={comp1.id} />, <Comp2 key={comp2.id} />, ...]

return (
  <div>
    {components}
  </div>
)
```

See [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) and [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children) in the React documentation.

Comment: i have keys in my example